# ReactJS: How can I get the owner of a component?

Tags: reactjs

ReactJS encourages one-way data flow but I want to break it for easier development where I need to two-way bound Input box.

I want a component like this

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            user: {
                name: ''
            }
        }
    },

    render: function(){

        return <TwoWayBinder type="input" model="user.name" />;

    }

});
```

where `user.name` is a variable in `this.state`. So, I want `<TwoWayBinder />` component to access the state of it's parent component (which is an anti-pattern according to React philosophy). I see that parent component is available in `_owner` property of TwoWayBinder component.

Is that the only way to access the owner? I don't want to use `valueLink` for multiple reasons.

Comment: This is terrible.

You should just forceRender and have the cycle start over from the top.

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html this maybe?

Answer (score 2):

There is no documented api for accessing the owner.  _owner is the only undocumented way (as far as I know).

> Update: "component._owner is no longer available in 0.13" -zbyte

---

I'm not a fan of valueLink personally.  I've been working on a similar but more powerful system.

In its lowest level form your code looks like this: [jsbin 1](http://jsbin.com/yutagoqixo/5/edit?js,output)

```
var App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [formMixin],
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      data: { name: "", email: "" }
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    var formData = this.stateKey("data");
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.data.name} onChange={formData.forKey("name").handler()} />
        <input type="text" value={this.state.data.email} onChange={formData.forKey("email").handler() } />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

That's not bad, and gives you a lot of control, but you might want something even quicker. [jsbin 2](http://jsbin.com/yutagoqixo/6/edit?js,output)

```
var Input = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var link = this.props.link;
    return <input type="text" 
                  {...this.props} 
                  value={link.getCurrentValue()} 
                  onChange={link.handler()} />
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [formMixin],
  getInitialState: function(){
      return { data: { name: "", email: "" } }
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    var formData = this.stateKey("data");
    return (
      <div>
        <Input link={formData.forKey("name")} />
        <Input link={formData.forKey("email")} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

For completeness, here's the full mixin:

```
var formMixinHandler=function(thisArg,keys,parent){return{forKey:function(key){return formMixinHandler(thisArg,keys.concat(key),this)},bindTo:function(newThisArg){return formMixinHandler(newThisArg,keys,this)},transform:function(fn){var obj=formMixinHandler(thisArg,keys,this);obj.transforms=obj.transforms.concat(fn);return obj},transforms:parent?parent.transforms:[],handler:function(){var self=this;return function(event){var value=event;if(event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement)if(event.target.type==="checkbox"||event.target.type==="radio")value=event.target.checked;else value=event.target.value;self.transforms.reduce(function(last,fn){return fn(last,event)},value);var targetObj=keys.slice(0,-1).reduce(function(obj,key){if(!obj[key])obj[key]={};return obj[key]},thisArg.state);targetObj[keys[keys.length-1]]=value;var updateObject={};updateObject[keys[0]]=thisArg.state[keys[0]];thisArg.setState(updateObject)}},getCurrentValue:function(){return keys.reduce(function(obj,key){return obj?obj[key]:null},thisArg.state)}}};var formMixin={stateKey:function(key){return formMixinHandler(this,[].concat(key))}};
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer.

Comment: component._owner is no longer available in 0.13

Comment: Thanks, added it to the top of the answer so people see it quickly.  If there's a new hack, feel free to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the question, there is really internal API to get the owner in version 0.13:

```
this._reactInternalInstance._currentElement._owner._instance
```

As you know, it's really not recommended.